# About Čech cohomology ring of finitistic spaces

Tags: at.algebraic-topology

It is well known that every element of positive degree in the Čech cohomology ring of a finitistic space is nilpotent. On the contrary, if every element of positive degree in the Čech cohomology ring of any space $X$ is nilpotent, then can we say something about the $X$ space?